# UIViewAnimations not displayed when app changes background to foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can able to pause and resume the UIViewAnimations by using below code

Pause:

```
CFTimeInterval paused_time = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
layer.speed = 0.0;
layer.timeOffset = paused_time;
```

Resume:

```
CFTimeInterval paused_time = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0f;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0f;
layer.beginTime = 0.0f;
CFTimeInterval time_since_pause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - paused_time;
layer.beginTime = time_since_pause;
```

But after pausing the animations when app goes to background, again entered to foreground those animations are not displaying in the view.  I am using UIImageView for UIViewAnimations.